# Integration of KonvaJS with webassembly

Tags: webassembly, konvajs, assemblyscript

I am working on a project where I have a requirement to render millions of shapes. The file which has information on all coordinates can have a size of ~500MB. I am planning to use web assembly in this so that I can use system memory for my complex operations.

AssmeblyScript is one of good typescript library which can be used in webAssembly. I am looking for an example of integration of KonvaJS with assemblyscript. any pointers here would be really helpful.